# Audio not working Arch Linux (CHROMEBOOK)

Tags: arch-linux, audio, chrome-book

So I have installed Arch Linux on an [HP Chromebook](https://support.hp.com/au-en/product/HP-Chromebook-14/8499337/model/9062659/drivers). I have tried everything to get the Audio on it to work. I only see 2 HDMI outputs when I run `aplay -l`

I am running ArchLinux 2017.06.01 Kernel 4.11.9-1-ARCH.
I have already installed `linux-max98090` and it didn't help at all.
Any ideas why it won't work?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and give us more information. How exactly does it "not work"? How are you testing? What is the output of `airplay -l` you mention? What sound card do you have? Why is `linux-max98090` relevant? The more you tell us the better the chances of someone being able to help you.

Comment: Use the `lspci` command and look for "Audio device" to get information about your sound card. Use `journalctl` and look for messages which are related to the sound driver, especially at system start up. If `linux-max98900` is a kernel module, try disabling and re-enabling it and se if there are error messages. For that effect, use `journalctl -f` to print out all new system messages, then use another terminal to disable and reenable the kernel module using `rmmod` and `modprobe`

Comment: I have linux-max98090 as it was a kernel patch for my sound card for Linux 4.4. It was broken in 4.5, My sound card is an Intel Corporation Atom Processor Z36xxx/Z37xxx Series High Definition Audio Controller (rev 0e)

Comment: If it's of any help you may want to look the Ubuntu-based [GalliumOS](https://wiki.galliumos.org/Hardware_Compatibility). They state that they have been able to bing up full support for HP Chromebook 14 G4 in their distribution where newer models still don't have audio. If you can make it work there it should be possible to find out how they did it since they publish everything on GitHub.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your link does not work, but if your Chromebook runs on Intel m5 (or any other Skylake) processor then you are out of luck, there is no Linux driver yet.

Answer (score -2):

run **pacman -Syu** on your terminal

> then run **pacman -S alsa-utils alsa-plugins alsa-lib**

this should fix your sounds drivers

Comment: `apt-get` on an Arch Linux installation?

Comment: `pacman` is for Arch Linux, `apt-get` is for Debian